# MySQL language bindings for D?

Tags: mysql, windows, d

Are there any existing, working MySQL language bindings for D (particularly D 2.0 under Windows) still being maintained, updated, or even remotely poked at?  Dozens of google searches mostly only point to some code previously hosted at http://www.steinmole.de/d/ by one Manfred Hansen, but this site is now dead and no mirrored copies seem to exist anywhere.

I did manage to find this: http://code.google.com/p/mysql4d/ as well as another project called DDBI that apparently only works with D 1.0 and Tango.  I am having trouble linking these, though.. more google searches indicate that I need to convert the libmysql.dll included with MySQL to a libmysql.lib using implib.exe, however the program seems to be failing for me:

```
>implib.exe /system libmysql.lib libmysql.dll     
Digital Mars Import Library Manager Version 7.6B1n
Copyright (C) Digital Mars 2000.  All Rights Reserved.
Error(10): Error: cannot read DLL input file
```

A google search for "cannot read DLL input file" reveals utter horror: zero results.  Am I doing something completely wrong, or do I have some version of MySQL whose DLL can no longer be converted?

Versions:

```
DMD32 D Compiler v2.056
MySQL Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.8, for Win64 (x86)
```

Comment: For posterity, it appears the problem I was having with the DLL was due to implib.exe apparently being unable to read 64-bit files.  I downloaded the 32-bit version of MySQL community server 5.1 and was able to pass that libmysql.dll through implib.exe to create a working, dmd-linkable import library.  Of course, I still got numerous Access Violation errors/segfaults from the various modules, but that's another matter entirely.  The pure D module mentioned in the answer below seems to get the job done though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several MySQL bindings, starting with this one: https://github.com/adamdruppe/misc-stuff-including-D-programming-language-web-stuff/blob/master/mysql.d

But (IMHO) the most promising project is the native D implementation of the MySQL protocol. It can be found here: https://github.com/britseye .

For the one you tried above, you need the [COFFIMPLIB](ftp://ftp.digitalmars.com/coffimplib.zip) tool to create an OMF version of the MySQL library `libmysql.lib` from the one distributed with MySQL for the `libmySQL.dll` file.

Update: These two forks of Steve's mysqln project are active: https://github.com/simendsjo/mysqln and https://github.com/rejectedsoftware/mysql-native .

Comment: Thanks for the info!  I will check those other projects out... however, I did try using COFFIMPLIB to convert the lib and/or dll included with MySQL 5.5  These two files are included with the distribution:

Comment: 4,175,872 libmysql.dll
       23,920 libmysql.lib
The tool does not run on the DLL,
    >coffimplib.exe libmysql.dll _libmysql.lib
    Error: missing archive signature
though it does run successfully on the libmysql.lib.  However, if I attempt to link against the resulting file, I still get the various 'Symbol Undefined _mysql_query' etc errors.

This is out of my typical realm of experience, but I'm wondering if the _ characters need to be added to the front of the function names somehow?  I recall this being a flag passable to implib.exe, but coffimplib.exe seems to have no such option.